# Android - How do I specify a location when calling the calendar with an intent?

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-intent

I'm creating an `Intent` to create a new calendar event from my application.  I'm trying to figure out how to specify what should be in the "Where" field on the calendar item so I can put an address in it but what I've tried isn't working.  Does anyone know what

```
//Create our intent
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT); 
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("title", myTitle);
intent.putExtra("description", myDescription);
//Trying to get the where to wrk
intent.putExtra("where", myAddress);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've tried setting "where" as seen above but that is not working.

Comment: Make sure you format your code with the [code] tag please.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The location field is  "eventLocation"

```
intent.putExtra("eventLocation", myAddress)
```

Comment: or event better:
`intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, myAddress)`